# PsGetSID shows two usernames and one SID

Tags: active-directory, sid, sysinternals

We changed the logon name of a person in AD from 'name1' to 'name2'. We had problems with some sql boxes picking up the old 'name2' and using it to authenticate so in tracking down why I ran:

```
psgetsid name1
```

and

```
psgetsid name2
```

, both give me the same SID. How can one SID have two usernames attached? I have checked the 'Active Directory Users and Computers' mmc snap in and searched the domain for users, contacts or groups>> Name = 'name1' and then 'name2'. Sure enough I get a common result but 'name2' is nowhere to be found in the common result('name1' is the logon name listed for example and it's also in the email field).

Comment: I also went to powershell and ran `Get-AdUser -Identity name1 -Properties * `. One property of this AD account, mailNickname, is 'name2'. That's the only occurrence of 'name2'. Is it possible psgetsid looks for mailNickname?